# specific data is not coming in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am doing some practice on the codeigniter to retrieve the data from database and i am success to do this.but the problem arise when i want to fetch data of a specific field.
to retrieve the specific value i am using the following URL on my local host:

```
localhost/codeigniter/index.php/news/view/city-news
```

where news is controller,view is method of controller and city-news is argument.

**Here is my code of controller**:

```
public function view($slug)
    {

        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);//here i am getting the slug value.
                if (empty($data['news_item']))
            {
        show_404();
            }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

this method calls the method get_news($slug) of model news_model.here is the code of this method:

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
   {

    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    echo $slug;//here is i m also getting the slug value.
    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));//i think this is not working properly
    print_r($query->row_array());die;//now i am getting values here.   
    return $query->row_array();
   }
```

but still my view shows "404 page not found". my view code is:

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
?>
```

Now please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: no errors? And you're sure that the echoed `slug` variable is in the database?

Comment: @sven actully i die the array on model & want to see the values is coming or not thats why no error.and i am sure about the slug value.

Comment: @sven if i didnt use die and lets flow controll as it is than i got the error on view "404 page not found".

Comment: @dianuj plz see my above comment.its also reply of your question

Comment: is there slug in unique in db table

Comment: @Pramod no slug is not unique.

Comment: why are you checking empty($data['news_item'])? you don't have this array key initialized. am i right? You are declaring value for $data['news'] and then try to access $data['news_item']

Comment: @ŁukaszAdamczewski ,my controll is not going till the empty($data['news_item']).before this i am die the array and this array is giving blank data.

Comment: You get empty array so there must be some issue with comparing slug column to value from request. You should double check this, check manually db result when calling 
`select * from news where slug = 'city-news';`

Comment: try print_r($query->row_array());

Comment: @ŁukaszAdamczewski ,it gives fine result in db.

Comment: you get a blank array because codeigniter doesnt yet know whether to treat $query as object or array , you need to print_r($query->array()) or such , plus really not recommended to print stuff in the model

Comment: @all..now i got the value in  print_r($query->array()),but still my view shows "404 page not found."

Comment: @all now please see my updated question.now i solved some problem but still some issue.

Comment: try if(empty($data)) instead of if(empty($data['news_items']))

Comment: i answered you already You don't have news_item index in $data array

Comment: @user1537158 if i use empty($data['news_items']) than it gives error of undefined on $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

Comment: @ŁukaszAdamczewski,so can you please tell me to how to manage the code of controller ? cause if i didnt use $data['news_item'] than it shows undefined in views.so please give anser about this two part(controller & view) using my code.thanks

Comment: as i think You have news row data in  $data['news'] variable so for sure var_dump($data['news']) to check column names and then $data['title'] = $data['news']['title']; and $news instead of $news_item in template

Comment: @HarshalMahajan true that , but you dont have $data['new_items'] you have $data['news'] so test that for empty

Comment: @user1537158 if i test with $data[news] and show on view $data[news] than it gives error of undefined $data variable.

Comment: no , on the view you must use $news and not $data , keys of array in controller are converted to variables on view in codeigniter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your error is you are setting `$data['news']` and testing `$data['news_item']` :

```
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);//here i am getting the slug value.

if (empty($data['news_item'])) // <=== HERE IS THE ERROR
{
    show_404();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer,so can you please tell me how i can manage controller & view code?

Comment: instead of `if (empty($data['news_item']))` write `if (empty($data['news']))`

Comment: i did that but in to the view when i tried to echo the $data['news']; than it gives undefined variable $data error.

Comment: you must echo $news in the view

Comment: in your view you should use `$news` and not `$data['news']`, `var_dump($news)` helps you

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with simple `where` query as follows

```
$data = $this->db->where('slug', $slug)->from('news');
```

you must get something in `$data`. Means at least mysql object. Its been another part that whether rows are available in database or not.

secondly i am worried about the true and false. Means as per i know `Boolean` store as `INT(1)` means either 0 or 1. You needs to check with that as well.

you can debug your query with

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldnt it be where('slug',$slug) ?

Comment: @user1537158 ups.. my mistake.. edited.. i am not using codeigniter anymore from last 6 months.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @kuku Thnaks for answer,but i sort out this.but still some issue.you can see my updated question.

Comment: @Ahmad answered better than me.. thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cleaned code of the controller:

```
public function view($slug)
{

    $news = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
            if (empty($news))
        {
    show_404();
        }

    $data['title'] =$news['title'];
    $data['text'] = $news['text'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

this method calls the method get_news($slug) of model news_model:

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{

if ($slug === FALSE)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();
}
echo $slug;
$query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
print_r($query->row_array());die;//now i am getting values here.   
return $query->row_array();
```

}

```
<?php echo '<h2>'.$title.'</h2>'; echo
$text; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small error:
Here

```
if (empty($data['news_item'])) // <=== put "news" here
{
    show_404();
}
```

and at your view try to get data as

```
echo $news;
```

Answer (score -1):

die() is a function use exit instead.

set this at the beginning of script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

also use var_dump($query); to check if it return any result if not exception or fatal error was raised when calling query

if array is empty it means that no news with this slug is in db. You should set some conditions when particular news is not found

also what is the value of this slug, does it contain any special chars etc.?

Comment: i think there is no issue of die,if i didnt use die than nothing is shows on view.

Comment: i alredy set the $config['log_threshold'] = 1;in config file and still facing same issue.